# does convexity implies $g(u)>cu$?

Tags: calculus, convex-analysis

So I have been doing some self study and I was wondering if my results are true, or if I am misreading something.

Say we have a function $g$ which is concave on values of $u \in \mathbb{R}$.
Then we know that
$$
  \frac{d^2}{du^2}g(u)\geq0
$$
which means:
$$
  \frac{d}{du}g(u) \geq c\text{,  for some }c\in\mathbb{R}
$$
$$
  \implies g(u)\geq c\cdot u +b\text{,  for some }b\in\mathbb{R}
$$

So does this mean that convexity implies that all the points in your function are greater than those on any line?
Because I feel like I am missing some restrictions here on $c,b$.

Comment: concave means $\frac{d^2}{du^2}g(u)\leq 0$. Also, it's not true that the first derivative is bounded below. For example, $y(x)=x^4$ has $\frac{d^2}{dx^2}x^4=12x^2\geq 0$ but $\frac{d}{dx}x^4=4x^3$ is not bounded below by any $c$.

Comment: @AlexR. sorry, is convex the proper term?

Comment: what about $x\to (x-2)^2$ it's convex but $\cdots$

Comment: @AlexR. what if I were to restrict the domain to be $[0,\infty]$?

Comment: @asosnovsky: $g(u)=1/u$ has positive second derivative, but not positive first derivative.

Comment: actually for any convex function $f$ there exists $\alpha$ and $a$ such that $f(x)\geq a(x-\alpha)$